# Error SQL: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into [...]

Tags: oracle-11g, insert, autoincremento

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto? Sé que es básico, pero recién estoy entrando a este mundo:

```
insert into alumnos(nombre,apellido,rut,fecha_nacimiento)
values ('marco', 'castro','12476251-0','1972-10-21');
```

El error se localiza la línea 2.

Informe de error:

> Error SQL: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   ("SYSTEM"."ALUMNOS"."ID")
>   01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y coloca un título acorde a las necesidades de tu pregunta de un modo mas objetivo

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Estás recibiendo este error porque no has puesto todos los campos necesarios de la tabla `alumnos` para poder insertar un nuevo registro y, precisamente, el campo que te falta no puede ser `NULL`.

```
insert into alumnos(nombre,apellido,rut,fecha_nacimiento,campo_necesario)
values ('marco', 'castro','12476251-0','1972-10-21','valor_necesario');
```

Sustituye `campo_necesario` (probablemente `ID`) y `valor_necesario` por lo que proceda y te funcionará.

También puedes definirlo como autonumérico y así evitar introducir tú los `ID` manualmente en cada inserción

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce porque no pones el campo id en el insert.
El campo ID debe estar configurado de forma que no admite valores null. Al no definir el valor por el campo ID en el insert, intenta inserir el registro con un null para este campo dando a lugar al error.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/338507)